# How to do a CBV CreateView with Extended user model django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-users

I am currently learning about CBVs and what they provide in django. I am wondering how does one approach CBV CreateView for both the User model and Extended User Model so the page can display the accumulative fields for both?

For example if I had this Extended model (example from django):
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

And have this basic CBV setup:

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .models import Employee


class UserCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Employeee
    fields = ['department']


# employee_form.html
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Save">
    </form>
```

What ways does django provide that can allow this CBV to also display user fields to also be created in conjunction with employee?

Comment: You can use inline formsets, an example:  https://gist.github.com/neara/6209563

Comment: Yes this is perfect, thanks!